# getting CC1plus.exe fatal error: c:\mydirectory\include no such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, oracle

I am trying to get the oracle interface OCI and OCCI working in eclipse/windows environment.  I have a very basic "lets see if we get an error with this setup" program.

```
#include <oci.h>
#include <occiCommon.h>

int main(){
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    return 0;
}
```

i loaded the oracle client with the header files etc into c:\users\paul\oracle\sdk\include The default location.  i have added the path in eclipse C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Linker -> libraries for C and C++.   I have also entered the path under C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> includes, and library paths, and also Libraries.   If i expand the Includes under project explorer, i can see my header files listed along with the standard g++ header files.
When i build the project i get "cc1plus.exe: fatal error: c:\users\paul\oracle\sdk\include: No suh file or directory"...
I've tried about everything i can think of to get this cleared.  Anyone have an idea what to try next?
Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess:  are there any directory permissions that may be keeping `cc1plus.exe` from accessing that directory? I assume you double-checked to see if there are files named `oci.h` and `occiCommon.h` in that directory?

Comment: Yes, the first thing i checked.  was the existence and location of the files....  and both the sdk and eclipse are owned by me...  
one more piece of information i should have included above:  here is the Gcc output:
g++ "-IC:\\Users\\paul\\Oracle\\sdk\\include" "-include:\\Users\paul\\Oracle\\sdk\\enclude" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp"

Comment: OK,  I figured out the problem.  I plead ignorance.  While setting up the environment in eclipse :   Properties -> Settings -> C++ compiler -> Includes    i entered the path for the include files,  but not the actual file names, in the include files section.  Stupid mistake i admit, i think i made the assumption that if the path is listed, the compiler would automatically find the actual files...   Oh well,

Comment: Not a stupid mistake; I'd have thought the same thing; I love command lines but avoid IDEs so a reasonable expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem lies in the name of your `.cpp` file name. Please do not give any space inside the name of the `.cpp` file. In my case, this same problem was solved this way:

**Previous Solving:**

[image: Previous Solving]

**Solved:**

[image: After Solved]